# Is there any mention by our sages of blessed memory of Jews living in Central Asia?

Tags: rabbis, golus-exile

Is there any mention by our sages of blessed memory of Jews living in Central Asia: Iran Azerbaijan, Turkmenistan, Uzbekistan, Kazakhstan, Tajikistan, Kyrgyzstan, Afghanistan, Pakistan, Xinjiang, Caucasus area, Armenia, Georgia.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bukharan_Jews#History
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Jews_in_Iran

Comment: Is this any more on topic than: `Is there any mention by our sages of blessed memory of French Toast recipes?`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Jews not Judaism, just as the question: "Is there any mention by our sages of blessed memory of French Toast recipes?" would be about food; not Judaism.

Answer (score 1):

The biblical book of Esther describes the Jews in "the kingdom of Persia and Media", which is roughly Iran and Azerbaijan today. As noted in the comments, there have been many Jews in present-day Iran for a very, very long time.

The Talmud uses "Media" (again, present-day Azerbaijan) as an example of a far-flung, but still accessible place. `You're obligated to return something you stole, even if it means going all the way to Media.` And `Well this item may not be worth much around here, but maybe it's worth something in Media?`

Comment: You might enjoy reading a translation of the travels of Benjamin of Tudela. See this link for background. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benjamin_of_Tudela#

Comment: Also, you don't need a written source. We have a clear archeological record like for example the large Jewish community that was at Yeghegis in Armenia. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Jews_in_Armenia